# Taylor's theorem & steepest descent

Tags: optimization, numerical-optimization

In "Numerical Optimization" by  Jorge Nocedal and Stephen J. Wright derive the direction of steepest descent from Taylor's theorem:

[image]

I do not understand how I can get to formula (2.13). Why can I ignore the quadratic part of 2.13?

Comment: They are just saying that if you have an affine model of the cost $f$ (that is the first two terms of the Taylor representation) and you fix a step size to some particular length (one here) then the best direction for a decrease is given by a solution to (1). The reason they fix the step size is that the problem would be unbounded otherwise.

Comment: As an aside, if the Hessian at $x_k$ was positive definite, then solving the problem $\min_p p^T \nabla f(x_k) + {1 \over 2} p^T H(x_k)p$ would give the Newton step.

Comment: As a further aside (and I personally prefer this viewpoint), the direction you get is the same as solving the previous problem with $H$ replaced by the identity matrix. (The solution is just $p_k = - \nabla f(x_k)$ which will typically not be of length one, but the direction will be the same.)

Comment: Thank you for your comments so far. Can you tell me what "affine model of the cost" means (or point me somewhere)?
I get your second and third comment, but still not the original question. Why is only the  $\alpha p^T \nabla f(x_k) $ minimized, but not $\frac{1}{2} \alpha^2 p^T \nabla^2 f(x_k + tp)p$?
Why is the direction of steepest descent independent of the second term?